# Is it a good practice to add classes from hover.css with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have a a project where i have to add hover effects in the html. Is it a good practice to do this with jQuery addClass() method or it's better do to it manually all over the html

Comment: why do it in js when you can do it in css?

Comment: There are some cases where jQuery could be a better choice. But in general I would agree, *css first*.

Comment: css can that alone

Comment: I use css library hover.css, which uses raedy classes. I have lots of places in my html where i have you use these hover.css clasess(I have to add them in the html). My question was "Is it a good practice to add the classes via jQuery, or it's better to do it manually"

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would prefer to use **CSS** for simple effects like this instead of JavaScript when you can.

In some **specific cases**, JS could be better, but it depends on your situation and the state of your code.

---

From what I see, I guess you would better create a CSS class and apply it all over your HTML code. Don't write JS code for that.

Comment: In general I agree. But how can you say *but here I suggest you to create a CSS class and apply* without knowing it's code and usecase? You're just guessing.

Comment: I guess it is a general answer, since we has no access to his code... Maybe am I a bit guessing ;P

Comment: But you agree with me, that we don't know it for sure. So don't answer on things you don't know. :)

Comment: I agree with you, I rewrote my answer to be more prudent. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> *"I use css library hover.css, which uses ready classes. I have lots of places in my html where i have you use these hover.css classes(I have to add them in the html)."*

Judging from your comment, I'm wondering if you are aware that hover states can be added to elements via CSS without actually changing classes (or even adding them at all).

You can use the [CSS :hover pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) to change the style of an element when the user hovers over it.

**CSS**

```
a {
    color: red;
}
a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

In this example, all `<a>` tags will be red by default, and when you hover over them they will turn blue.

You can use the same pseudo-class with any other normal class:

```
.my-class {
    color: pink;
}
.my-class:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

Any elements with the class `my-class` will then be pink, and when you hover they will turn green.

```
<p class="my-class">Hover over me to turn me green</p>
```

Using this method, it's completely unnecessary to use jQuery to toggle classes on elements just to provide a hover state. I guess there might be some rarer cases where you might want to do that for some reason, but I suspect you don't need to.